# How to cite a meta discusion in edit comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, edit-summary

Let's say there is a meta discussion about retagging, and I would like to go through a few questions to retag them according to the outcome of the discussion.

I think it would be helpful to cite the meta discussion in the edit comment to give a reason for the change, so I don't have to write a full description for the edit and people can see where they can join to the discussion.

Is this an acceptable thing to do? If yes, then what is the proper way to cite the meta discussion? I thought something like:

> Retag according to meta discussion: {questionid}

Answer (score 4):

Most folks just paste the URL of the meta discussion into the edit description.

Ideally, you'll also include a bit of text summarizing what you're doing - don't *force* folks to meta to understand the reason for the edit.